# Mixing "nounset" with "$@" in ksh

Tags: shell, ksh

I have a script that needs to forward all of its parameters to a different program.  Additionally, for cleanliness purposes I keep the shell option `nounset` enabled.

Consider the following example script:

```
#!/bin/ksh
set -o nounset

# Pass all of our parameters (plus a few extra) to our target
printf "<%s>\n" "Parameter count: $#" "$@"
```

The above works fine as long as the main calling script has at least one parameter.  If it has no parameters, it results in `ksh: @: parameter not set` and the script terminates.

```
$ ./dollar_at.sh "Hello" "World"
<Parameter count: 2>
<Hello>
<World>


$ ./dollar_at.sh ""
<Parameter count: 1>
<>


$ ./dollar_at.sh
./dollar_at.sh[5]: @: parameter not set
```

If I disable the `nounset` option, we get the following:

```
$ ./dollar_at.sh
<Parameter count: 0>
```

Incidentally, `nounset` under `bash` handles an empty `$@` without error, but the environment for this script doesn't have `bash` as an option.

---

**Is there a way to make `ksh` play nice with an empty `$@`?**
Ideally, I'd like `"$@"` to expand into zero parameters, just as `bash` does and `ksh` does without `nounset` enabled.

So far I've only come up with two possible workarounds, neither of which I'm very satisfied with:

1. Wrap the target command in `if (( $# > 0 ))` and conditionally pass `$@`.  I dislike this option because there are other constant parameters that must always be passed and this results in duplicated code.
2. Toggle the `nounset` option any time I need to access `$@`.  This feels like bad practice and defeats the purpose of having `nounset` enabled to begin with.

Comment: Once the script is working, you don't need to keep the `nounset` option active.  If you need to modify the script and debug it again, then you can add it back in.  This sounds like a case of "Doctor, Doctor, it hurts when I hit my head with a hammer" — the prescription is the same: "Stop hitting your head with a hammer".  If you're depending on environment variables being set, or read from a configuration file, then you can explicitly check those that matter.  Or you can turn the option off for the section of the script where you invoke the other program — as you suggest.  I'd not test `$#`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - That's like telling a Perl user to remove `use warnings` and `use strict` if the script isn't throwing errors.  I don't want to disable safety features, I just want to suppress the false alarm case when `$# == 0` and `$@` is accessed.

Comment: IMNSHO, I disagree with the comparison to Perl warnings/strictures — I've never found `nounset` of any relevance (well, I've never felt the slightest need for it in the last 30 or so years of shell scripting).  However, you can simply turn `nounset` off around the places where you use `"$@"`.  I think that's going to be cleanest if you can't switch to Bash, which you said you can't do.

Comment: @Mr.Llama, `use warnings` and `use strict` are actually well-designed, inasmuch as anything in Perl is. That's *absolutely* not the case for `set -e` (which creates more surprises, ambiguities, and cross-version incompatibilities than it resolves), and there's a case to be made that it's not the case for `set -o nounset` either.

Comment: I can't reproduce with your code. What version of ksh are you using? (I have 93u+)

Answer (score 0):

When you keep the `set -o nounset`, keep the special handling on 1 place: a function.

```
function forwarder {
   target=$1
   shift
   if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
      "${target}"
   else
      "${target}" "$@"
   fi
}

set -u
forwarder ./dollar_at.sh hello world
forwarder ./dollar_at.sh hello
forwarder ./dollar_at.sh ""
forwarder ./dollar_at.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

```
printf "${@:-}"
```

Colon after variable allows specifying default value. See more at [KSH variable substitutions](http://www.softpanorama.org/Scripting/Shellorama/String_operations/ksh_substitutions.shtml).